# How to add post under particular pages? Like website.com/page1/post1

Tags: posts, pages

I want to add posts under particular pages and dont want to show them under home page or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the head of the post('page parent') in the side bar (under page attributes) when creating a new post.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#To_create_a_subpage

Change the head to page1 for example to make the new post a sibling of page1.